# Creating a makefile with different tests

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to understand if I have create the Makefile right. I have the following files:

```
Student.h Student.C University.h University.c list.h IDCard.h IDCard.c union.h
```

Also I have a library `mylib` which I use the `list.h` and `union.h` from.
Furthermore, I have the following hierarchy:

```
- University
    - Student
        - list
        - IDCard
    - union
```

This means that `University` imports `Student` and `union` and `Student` import `list` and `IDCard`.

The steps I need to follow:

1. Use the make command to create `testing1.exe` - release mode without asserts. This file is the runnable of the given `testing1.c`.
2. Use `make testing2.exe` for creating `test2.exe` - release mode without asserts. This file is the runable of `testing2.c`.
3. Use `make testing2_debug.exe`  for creating `testing2_debug.exe` -  debug mode, with asserts. This file is the runable of `test2.c`.
4. Use `make test` for creating `test.exe` - release mode without asserts. This file is runnable of `test.c`.
5. Use `make clean` to clean so the rebuild will succeed.

The Makefile I wrote looks like:

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = IDCard.o Student.o University.o
DEBUG_OBJS = IDCard_debug.o Student_debug.o University_debug.o
SOURCE = IDCard.c Student.c University.c
HEADER = IDCard.h Student.h University.h list.h union.h
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic-errors -Werror -DNDEBUG -L. -mylib
EXEC = testing.exe testing1.exe testing2.exe testing2_debug.exe
testing_O = testing1.o testing2.o testing2_debug.o testing.o

#make testing1.exe
testing1.exe : $(OBJS) $*.o
    $(CC) -o $@ -DNDEBUG $(OBJS) -L. mylib

#make testing2.exe
testing2.exe : $(OBJS) $*.o
    $(CC) -o $@ -DNDEBUG $(OBJS) -L. mylib

#testing2_debug.exe
testing2_debug.exe : $(DEBUG_OBJS) $*.o
    $(CC) -o $@ -DNDEBUG $(OBJS) -L. mylib

#make testing.exe
testing.exe : $(OBJS) $*.o
    $(CC) -o $@ -DNDEBUG $(OBJS) -L. mylib

testing1.o : testing1.c Student.h University.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $(CFLAGS) $*.c
Student.o : list.h IDCard.h Student.c Student.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $(CFLAGS) $*.c
University.o :  union.h University.c University.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $(CFLAGS) $*.c
IDCard.o : IDCard.h
    $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $(CFLAGS) $*.c

testing2_debug.o : testing2.c Student.h University.h
    $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $@
Student_debug.o : list.h IDCard.h Student.c Student.h
    $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $@
University_debug.o : union.h University.c University.h
    $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $@
IDCard_debug.o : IDCard.h
    $(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $@

clean :
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEBUG_OBJS) $(EXEC) $(testing_O)
```

I'm a bit new to creating Makefiles so I'm try to make as few mistakes as possible. Does my Makefile do what I need? Can it be simplified? Does it follow the conventions?

Comment: If you have something that works, and you want to know how it can be improved, [CodeReview.SE] is the place.

Comment: It looks as if this makefile will work, but much refactoring is possible. Note that if you rearrange the prerequisites to put the source file first (e.g. "foo.o: foo.h bar.h foo.c" => "foo.o: foo.c foo.h bar.h"), then you can use the [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$<` instead of `$*.c`. And when you start using [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), you can simplify this makefile quite a lot.

Comment: @Beta Do you mind to show how?

Comment: Now that I look more closely, I see a couple of things that look like actual bugs. Have you tried building files with this?

Answer (score 1):

`$*.o` shouldn't be a dependency. `$(OBJS)` already covers that.

As a general rule, you can avoid targets for individual object files.

Here's an example target that may need modification to suit your needs:

```
%.o: %.c %.h
<tab>$(CC) -DNDEBUG -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%_debug.o: %.c %.h
<tab>$(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

This requires the header file to have the same base name as the source file.

Another option that may work is listing off the header file dependencies of each object file and then doing the matching:

```
testing1.o: Student.h University.h
Student.o: list.h IDCard.h Student.h
University.o: union.h University.h
IDCard.o: IDCard.h
testing2_debug.o: Student.h University.h
Student_debug.o: list.h IDCard.h Student.h
University_debug.o: union.h University.h
IDCard_debug.o: IDCard.h

%.o: %.c
<tab>$(CC) -DNDEBUG -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%_debug.o: %.c
<tab>$(CC) -c -g $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

A similar rule can be followed for `.exe` files:

```
%.exe: $(OBJS)
<tab>$(CC) -DNDEBUG $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -L. -lmylib

%_debug.exe: $(DEBUG_OBJS)
<tab>$(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -L. -lmylib
```

Also, make sure to replace `<tab>` in these examples with hard tabs for your Makefile to be valid.

Comment: He needs individual targets for individual .o files because his .h dependency tree is not trivial. Otherwise, a better answer than mine.

Comment: @Joshua I added a slightly better rule that should work.

Comment: I don't think that rule works. Dependencies of all don't propagate like that. All isn't a keyword.

Comment: Now we have a really good answer. Too bad I can't upvote twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
IDCard.o : IDCard.h
        $(CC) -c -DNDEBUG $(CFLAGS) $*.c
```

but `.h` files aren't compiled

As a general style form list `.c` dependencies before `.h` dependencies.

EDIT: Community Wiki. If it weren't for the clarifying comment by OP I would now delete this post.

Comment: So, how to compile it? Is it the only mistake? How should the final `makefile` look like?

Comment: @vesii: You don't compile `.h` files so just remove those two lines and any other references to `DCard.o` (unless there really is an `IDCard.c` file somewhere).

Comment: oh oops, I forgot to mention it. there is a `IDCard.C` file. I'll edit.